# laravel : delete all dropmenu if the list is empty

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys

I am trying to get a side menu from db using user permission.  I successfully get the data but if it is empty i would like to delete the dropmenu:

```
@foreach ($t as $key=>$item)
    @if($ci)
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">{{$item->designation}}</span>
        </a>
        @foreach ($item->links as $link)
            @foreach($link->profil as $p)
                @if(Auth::user()->name == $p->login)
                    @php $ci = 1; @endphp
                        <ul class="submenu">

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{asset('/')}}{{$link->url}}">{{$link->titre}}</a>
                            </li>

                           </ul>
                           @else
                               @php $ci = 0; @endphp
                           @endif
                       @endforeach
                    @endforeach
            </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

details :

- the variable item get all main dropmenus
- the variable link get all link for each dropmenu
- the variable p for checking permission

Please could help me to fix this issue which is delete the empty dropmenu where if statement condition not applied

Answer (score 0):

I think your mean is :

```
@foreach ($t as $key=>$item)
@if($ci)
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle">
       <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><span class="mtext">{{$item->designation}}
       </span>
    </a>
    @foreach ($item->links as $link)
      @if($item->links->count())
        @foreach($link->profil as $p)
            @if(Auth::user()->name == $p->login)
                @php $ci = 1; @endphp
                    <ul class="submenu">

                        <li>
                            <a href="{{asset('/')}}{{$link->url}}">{{$link->titre}} 
                            </a>
                        </li>

                       </ul>
                       @else
                           @php $ci = 0; @endphp
                       @endif
                   @endforeach

              @endif

    @endforeach
        </li>
 @endif
@endforeach
```

add a `@if($links->count()` for if count of links bigger of zero continue process

Comment: no sir , you see @if($ci) from there i have to prevent if the user hasn't permission in db